# select query on mysql to select value from a single table according to a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql table with structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `engine4_user_fields_values` (
  `item_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`field_id`,`index`)
)
```

I want to select rows with field_id ='17' AND value IN(5,8,7)+field_id ='20' AND values IN(73,76)

I could not select it like given below, since if field_id is 17 it will not be 20!

```
SELECT * FROM `engine4_user_fields_values` WHERE (field_id ='17' AND value IN(5,8,7)) AND (field_id ='20' AND value IN(73,76))
```

If we use OR then it will select the value satisfying any of the condition.

Shall we use join for that? I am not sure about the code!
Any one please help me to get the select query for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `group by` item, and use a `having` clause to require that the item has rows that match both conditions:

```
select  item_id
from    engine4_user_fields_values
group by
        item_id
having  max(case when field_id ='17' and value in (5,8,7) then 1 end) = 1
        and max(case when field_id ='20' and value in (73,76) then 1 end) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sound like you should change the middle AND to OR. You want to return all rows that match first condition OR second condition. Field ID cannot be 17 AND 20.

```
SELECT * FROM `engine4_user_fields_values` WHERE (field_id ='17' AND value IN(5,8,7)) OR (field_id ='20' AND value IN(73,76))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using OR, but between the two subconditions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `engine4_user_fields_values` 
WHERE (field_id ='17' AND value IN(5,8,7))
OR (field_id ='20' AND value IN(73,76))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using + for field_id ='17' AND value IN(5,8,7)+field_id ='20' AND values IN(73,76)
so technically it is not possible to have field_id ='17' AND field_id ='20' at same time
You need to use OR instead of AND as below

```
SELECT * FROM `engine4_user_fields_values` WHERE (field_id ='17' AND value IN(5,8,7)) OR (field_id ='20' AND value IN(73,76))
```